# Why cant I get Data from the Google OAuth API through PHP?

Tags: php

I have a login script created which allows you to login through the Google API. Everything works fine and the redirect back to my website does also work.

Here is my script for the oauth callback:

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client-2.2.1/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

if (isset ($_GET["error"])) {

    header('Location: #');

} 

if (isset ($_GET["code"])) {

    $client = new Google_Client();  
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['g_access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();    


    $redirect = "http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset ($_SESSION["g_access_token"])) {

    $plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);
    $client->setAccesToken($_SESSION["g_access_token"]);
    $me = $plus->people->get('me');

    $_SESSION["unid"] = $me["id"];
    $_SESSION["g_name"] = $me["displayName"];
    $_SESSION["email"] = $me["emails"][0]["value"];
    $_SESSION["g_profile_image_url"] = $me["image"]["url"];
    $_SESSION["g_cover_image_url"] = $me["cover"]["coverPhoto"]["url"];
    $_SESSION["g_profile_url"] = $me["url"];
}
?>
```

I dont get any error, but the session variables are still undefined. Where is the problem?
I just read and watched lots of tutorials, but still dont get it. Maybe somebody can help me here!

Thank you :)

**EDIT**

I just debugged my code and now I know that the Session Variable 'g_access_token' is empty after the login. So the main reason why it doesnt work should be the authentication. But I still dont know how to solve that...

Comment: What does `$me` contain? Is it what you expected? Does the code definitely go into that block? You need to do some debugging. "setAccesToken" looks wrong - "setAccessToken" is more likely. Make sure you have error reporting turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just come from dealing successfully with Google OAuth API for PHP. So far, your code doesn't seem broke. Anyhow, it'd be nice to check your config file from which you get the class **new Google_Client(**).

As that file is not posted in your question, i recommend you to follow this one, and call it through **require_once** to whenever you need it:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once "GoogleAPI/vendor/autoload.php";
    $gClient = new Google_Client();
    $gClient->setClientId("your_client_id_comes_here");
    $gClient->setClientSecret("your_client_secret");
    $gClient->setApplicationName("CPI Login Tutorial");
    $gClient->setRedirectUri("your_authorized_uri.php");
//addScope sets the permissions you'll have in your app, whether it is only for displaying them or to handle as you desire (e.g.: store account's information, such as email givenName and so on, into your own db
    $gClient->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me");
?>
```

Also, don't you forget to enable the Google + API in your Google console. Finally, check that in your credentials, the "Authorized redirect URIs" contains the redirect uri you want the google api to callback once the user is authenticated.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I just copied the code you've written and inserted all values, but it still doesnt work. The problem doesnt seem to be the oAuth 'Opener', its the Call where I want to access all relevant informations about the user. But there is the problem, I just cant. The Variable is still empty after the login and I really do not know why...

Comment: I don't know whether it  is allowed here in SO to share links, but this video is very concise and updated (it was made in August, last year), and it made my day,( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hazMyK_cnzk ) . Take a look and try it, maybe you can turn your code to that example and make it work.

Comment: Something that the vid doesn't mention is that, sometimes, you have to adjust your account's security settings as to allow third-party, or unknown, apps access your information (in this case, your system'd be that app). You can change those settings of the account you're using in this link:
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Wow thank you! That Video really helped me out. I just wrote the whole code completly new and now it works fine. My only problem now is, that after a logout and a relogin I cant get the users Data because "the code was already redeemed" (as the google error says). Do you also know how to fix that?

Comment: I don't have a clue about why that error turns up (maybe, you should post a question focusing on that). However, here are some tips:
 - Be sure to be logged in with your gmail account (oebspm' response: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/issues/82)
 - Add the proper and correct URIs to return when calling back from the login view
 - Check the OAuth Documentation, especially Step 4 and 5 in the following link as they're related in how to handle Google's server response and tokens ( https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer?hl=en#example )